# Will AD B2C userflow roll over key to sign JWT?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am using the predefined userflow and use the public key that AD B2C provides in jwks_uri to validate the token on my side. My question is whether that public key will be changed later?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. As the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#validate-signature) states:

> Azure AD B2C rotates the possible set of keys periodically. Your
> application should be written to handle those key changes
> automatically. A reasonable frequency to check for updates to the
> public keys used by Azure AD B2C is every 24 hours. To handle
> unexpected key changes, your application should be written to
> re-retrieve the public keys if it receives an unexpected kid value.

```
https://contoso.b2clogin.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin1/discovery/v2.0/keys
```

> The JSON document located at this URL contains all the public key
> information in use **at a particular moment**.

So the keys will be changed periodically and you should handle those key changes automatically by always getting the latest signing keys using the OpenID Connect discovery document.